# How do I compare text in Excel cells to see if same words are found?

Tags: excel, vba, comparison, cells

I have several rows of Excel cells which contain a string of words, all separated by commas. I want to compare each cell with another cell to check if any of the words match/are duplicates. 
For example:

cell A1: `dog, cat, rabbit, mouse, lion, bear, tiger`
cell A2: `sausage, pickle, dog, cat, elephant, bread`

result: `dog, cat`

The result could also be a number (e.g. 2) if that is easier.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be best served using VBA which you could then deploy as a `User Defined Function` (UDF)

- hold down [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11)  to go to the VBE
- *Insert ...  Module*
- copy and paste in the code below
- hold down [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) to go back to Excel

Then call the function in Excel such as
`=DupeWord(A1,A2)`
to find any matches between A1 and A2

[image]

**`Usr Defined Function`**

```
Function DupeWord(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
Dim vArr1
Dim vArr2
Dim vTest
Dim lngCnt As Long
vArr1 = Split(Replace(str1, " ", vbNullString), ",")
vArr2 = Split(Replace(str2, " ", vbNullString), ",")
On Error GoTo strExit

For lngCnt = LBound(vArr1) To UBound(vArr1)
vTest = Application.Match(vArr1(lngCnt), vArr2, 0)
If Not IsError(vTest) Then DupeWord = DupeWord & vArr1(lngCnt) & ", "
Next lngCnt
If Len(DupeWord) > 0 Then
DupeWord = Left$(DupeWord, Len(DupeWord) - 2)
Else
strExit:
DupeWord = "No Matches!"
End If

End Function
```

**`Use inside VBA`**

```
Sub test()
MsgBox DupeWord("dog, cat, rabbit, mouse, lion, bear, tiger", "sausage, pickle, dog, cat, elephant, bread")
End Sub
```

Comment: brettdj, this is excellent thanks! exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 2):

[From here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/compare-cell-contents-HP003056130.aspx)

To check if the string is equal to another you can use `Exact`
`=EXACT(text1,text2)`

Text1     is the first text string.

Text2     is the second text string.

Comment: I tried using that, but it is for numbers & I'm not sure on the text-parsing part. That is the part I need help on :)

Comment: Like you can see in the example you can also compare strings to strings