# Excel/how to compare characters in the cells

Tags: vba, excel, compare, cells

I would like to compare characters in the cells and return the remain. For example,

A1 = (111, 222, 444, 555)

B1 = (111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666)

Then, I would like to see the remains in the cell C1,

C1 = (333, 666)

Is there any way I can do with excel functions? Do I have to do this with VBA code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probably need a VBA UDF for this - you can use Split() to break up each cell into a set of numbers and then compare the two sets.

Comment: Tim, I didn't know what the UDF meant and just googled it. (https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) I think I am able to do very basic VBA, but still have no idea what to do next, do you have any thought on that? Thanks,

Comment: This question is under the "Related" heading over on the right.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069890/how-do-i-compare-text-in-excel-cells-to-see-if-same-words-are-found?rq=1  Take a look at the code there.

Comment: Yes I will try this code into excel vba module and to see if this code will work. I thought that this might be accomplished by the depth of excel formula but truth is pretty complex :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Tim's comment, one possible UDF could look like this.

```
Public Function GetDiff(rngFirst As Range, rngSecond As Range) As String

    Dim arrFirst
    Dim arrSecond

    Dim lRctr1 As Long
    Dim lRctr2 As Long

    Dim bMatch      As Boolean
    Dim strResult   As String

    arrFirst = Split(IIf(Len(rngFirst) >= Len(rngSecond), rngFirst, rngSecond), ",")
    arrSecond = Split(IIf(Len(rngFirst) <= Len(rngSecond), rngFirst, rngSecond), ",")

    For lRctr1 = LBound(arrFirst) To UBound(arrFirst)
    bMatch = False
        For lRctr2 = LBound(arrSecond) To UBound(arrSecond)
            If (arrFirst(lRctr1) = arrSecond(lRctr2)) Then
                lRctr2 = UBound(arrSecond) + 1
                bMatch = True
            End If
        Next

        If Not bMatch Then
            strResult = strResult & arrFirst(lRctr1) & ","
        End If
    Next

    If Len(strResult) > 0 Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, 1, Len(strResult) - 1)
    End If

    GetDiff = strResult

End Function
```

---

Just add the above code in a module and then you can use it like this in let's say cell C1 `=GetDiff(A1,B1)`

Comment: cyboashu, hope this isn't too late to get back to you! Thank you So much your help, this works good as gold!

Comment: That's true, have a fantastic day Sir!

Comment: Hey cyboashu! hope you are doing well! I think I need a help to help on this, with this same UDF, the case of this doesn't work without knowing why! I've been digging this by myself but couldn't figure out . cell 1 = 309, 329, cell 2 = 329 and I expect cell 3 = 309. But the result was still 309, 329.  Do you have any idea I can fix the code? Thanks!