# How to seperate the cell values and compare in Excel using formula?

Tags: vba, excel, split, compare

I have two values (A and B) as shown in image below. I want to calculate the below mentioned values using A and B.

[image]

1. **Common:** Percentage of common values in A and B (e.g., only 4 is common in 1st example. So, the percentage is 1/4)
2. **Only A:** Percentage of only A items (e.g., in the first example 1, 5 are only in A. So the percentage is 2/4)
3. **Only B:** Percentage of only B items (e.g., in the first example 6 is only in B. So the percentage is 1/4)

I could not find a proper excel formula to divide the numbers in one cell by comma and compare it with the next column cell (e.g., 1,4,5 vs. 4,6). Please let me if there are any specific ms-excel formula that I can use for this.

I am happy to provide more details if needed :)

Comment: "Text to Columns" under the Data tab will split the cell by comma for you. Or, using VBA:  [**How do I compare text in Excel cells to see if same words are found?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069890/how-do-i-compare-text-in-excel-cells-to-see-if-same-words-are-found) as well as [**other possible solutions**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cells+comma+excel+compare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a UDF with option parameter for output calculation.

---

**Notes:**

**Function**  `GetPercentage`. Returns percentage according to option argument passed in.

**Arg1**: `rng1` range object 1 e.g. Cell A2

**Arg2**: `rng2` range object 2 e.g. Cell B2

**Arg3**: `calcOption` ; `"C"`  = Common , `"A"` is a only, `"B"` is B only.

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetPercentage(ByRef rng1 As Range, ByRef rng2 As Range, ByVal calcOption As String) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    'calcOption C  = Common , A is a only, B is B only.
    Dim arr1() As String, arr2() As String, totalAItems As Long, totalBItems As Long, totalItems As Long
    arr1 = Split(rng1.Value, ",")
    arr2 = Split(rng2.Value, ",")
    totalAItems = GetDistinctCount(arr1)
    totalBItems = GetDistinctCount(arr2)
    totalItems = GetDistinctCount(Split(rng1.Value & "," & rng2.Value, ","))
    Dim commonItemCount As Long
    commonItemCount = GetSharedCount(arr1, arr2)

    Select Case calcOption
    Case "C"
        GetPercentage = commonItemCount / totalItems
    Case "A"
        GetPercentage = OnlyInOneCell(arr1, arr2) / totalItems
    Case "B"
        GetPercentage = OnlyInOneCell(arr2, arr1) / totalItems
    End Select

End Function

Public Function GetDistinctCount(ByVal arr As Variant) As Long
    Dim tempDict As Object, i As Long
    Set tempDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not tempDict.Exists(arr(i)) Then tempDict.Add arr(i), arr(i)
    Next i

    GetDistinctCount = tempDict.Count

End Function

Public Function GetSharedCount(ByVal arr1 As Variant, ByVal arr2 As Variant) As Long
    Dim outCount As Long, i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(arr1(i), arr2, 0)) Then outCount = outCount + 1
    Next i

    GetSharedCount = outCount

End Function

Public Function OnlyInOneCell(ByVal arr1 As Variant, ByVal arr2 As Variant) As Long
    Dim outCount As Long, i As Long, tempDict As Object
    Set tempDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(arr1(i), arr2, 0)) Then
            If Not tempDict.Exists(arr1(i)) Then tempDict.Add arr1(i), arr1(i)
        End If
    Next i
    OnlyInOneCell = tempDict.Count
End Function
```

---

UDF in sheet

[image: UDF]

Comment: I managed to run it. Thank you so much once again for your great, great answer. very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for **common**.  Enter the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function Kommon(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim arry1, arry2, C As Collection

    arry1 = Split(s1, ",")
    arry2 = Split(s2, ",")

    Set C = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In arry1
            C.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
        For Each a In arry2
            C.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    On Error GoTo 0
    cc = CDbl(C.Count)

    For Each a In arry1
        For Each b In arry2
            If a = b Then
                k = k + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next b
    Next a

    Kommon = k / cc

End Function
```

Then use as follows:

[image]

the other two cases are small variation of this.